# Extract data from google font after decoding JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, iteration

I am trying to get all the Google font *family* values from this JSON response:

```
{
 "kind": "webfonts#webfontList",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "webfonts#webfont",
   "family": "ABeeZee",
   "category": "sans-serif",
   "variants": [
   "regular",
   "italic"
  ],
  "subsets": [
  "latin"
  ],
   "version": "v10",
   "lastModified": "2017-08-24",
   "files": {
    "regular": 
"http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v10/mE5BOuZKGln_Ex0uYKpIaw.ttf",
"italic": 
 "http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/abeezee/v10/kpplLynmYgP0YtlJA3atRw.ttf"
  }
 },
 ...
]
```

I am using this to get the above response:

```
$url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=My key';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$fonts = json_decode($result, true);
```

How do I loop through each items to get a list of all families?

Answer (score 0):

From the command line if having the output in json by using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) this could work:

```
curl <url> | jq '.items[].family'
```

By using PHP this may work:

```
$fonts = json_decode($result, true);
$families = array();
foreach($fonts as $key =>$value) {
    if ($key == "items") {
        foreach($value[0] as $k =>$v) {
            if ($k == "family") {
                array_push($families, $v);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the families will be stored in the `$families` array.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, one could declare an array, use [*foreach*](http://php.net) to loop through the items and push the family onto the array, but there are simpler techniques.

One approach is to use [array_column()](http://php.net/array_column) to handle looping through the results.

**Note**: this code doesn’t decode the results as an associative array (by passing `true` for [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) parameter `$assoc`) - instead it uses the decoded results as an object and ensures there is a property named *items*  by utilizing [property_exists()](http://php.net/property_exists). One could however keep the associative array syntax and ensure the key *items* exists by utilizing [array_key_exists()](http://PHP.net/array_key_exists).

```
$fonts = json_decode($result);
if (is_object($fonts) && property_exists($fonts, 'items')){
    $familyValues = array_column($fonts->items, 'family');
}
```

See a demonstration in [this playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/sl9h1dQZOb6dAA74).

Or for a functional approach, use [array_map()](http://php.net/array_map)

```
$fonts = json_decode($result);
if (is_object($fonts) && property_exists($fonts, 'items')){
    $familyValues = array_map(function($font) {
        return $font->family;
    }, $fonts->items);
}
```

[playground example](https://www.tehplayground.com/9vUm7zmXqM2vhOTZ)